# How to end node.js execution after the first matched route sends response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node.js with express and have all my controllers in a folder and are used like this:

```
controllers   
--index.js  
--error.js  
--post.js  
app.js
```

The controllers folder is loaded in app.js as so

`app.use(require('./controllers'));`

In the index.js inside controllers folder I have the following code to load all the actual controllers

```
router.use(require('./error'));
router.use(require('./post'));
```

In error.js I have a route of this structure:

```
router.get('/error', function(req, res){...});
```

In post.js I have a route like this:

```
router.get('/:postId', function(req, res){...});
```

Now the problem is that when I make a GET request to **/error**, it executes the /error route in error.js where it sends a response through `res.render()`, but after that continues to execute the /:postId route in post.js as it matches the url structure which is making the app crash. I've tried adding `res.end()` after `res.render()` in error.js and it didn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you concluding that that's what's crashing the app? Because unless you call `req.next()` from `/error` (which I hope you're not) I don't think it should even propagate on to `/:postId`. What exactly is the error message you're getting, and what are the contents of /error handler?

Comment: @laggingreflex I know it's running /:postId through console logs. Basically it's assuming there is a post with id="error" and trying to get it's attributes which is making it crash as I haven't added a case for when the post I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: But are you calling `next()` in **/error**? This is the only way it will ever get to **/:postId** route.

Comment: @Jordonias Nope I'm not calling next(). That's why I can't figure out how it's getting to /:postId.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think `res.send()` could work, but it didn't. Maybe if you pass a callback argument to `res.render(view, options, callback)` method, it can work.

Like the following;

```
res.render('error.html', {}, function(res) {
  res.end();
});
```

If you want, you can look [render method](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/2f8ac6726fa20ab5b4a05c112c886752868ac8ce/lib/response.js#L938) on response.js in express' repo.

And if it doesn't work, there is another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814994/2324048).

Answer (score 0):

Your "error" route has been overwritten by "post" route.

Actually you should use `'posts/:postId'` instead of `'/:postId'` since it may cause confusion on future.

E.g: `GET /welcome` or `GET /error` may be understood as `postId=welcome` or `postId=error`

Try this one:

```
router.use('/post', require('./post'));
```

Then things are much clearer:

```
`GET /error`
`GET /posts/12345`
```

Another solution (but not recommended) is changing the order:

```
router.use(require('./post'));
router.use(require('./error'));
```

Comment: Yes, I had to change the route to /post/postId instead to get it working.